# In QGIS, add to existing dem tiles and expand corresponding contour coverage within a project

Tags: qgis, dem, editing

In my first QGIS project I have dozens of digitized layers that have spread beyond the contour and dem tile area that I started with. Please recommend how to safely expand or replace the dem and contour layers with larger ones in the project.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'll need to source some more data. There's no way to expand your DEM or Contours without actually finding data.

I'd suggest that you look into your local, regional, or national government spatial agencies. Perhaps search for open data repositories in your area.

If all else fails, there's a global elevation model at around 30 m resolution called ASTER, which will be available in your area: http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

Comment: Thanks Alex. My question was poorly written. I do have the additional dems downloaded and can create contours of the larger area in a new project. My concern is placing that info into my existing project. Is it simply a matter of deleting existing dem tile set layer and associated contour layers and creating a new larger dem tile set area layer and new contour layers?

Comment: Hi @PaulRansom, just load it all in there. QGIS can handle a lot. If you save your project first, you can mess around and always get back to where you were before!